# SQL check if a column in a table is a subset of a column in another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 BigQuery tables like below:

**First example:**

[image]

I want to check if elems column in table 1 are subset of the elems column in table 2. In the first example above, the query should return nothing, because for `id` 1, all the `elems` 1001, 1002, 1004 exist in table 2 where `id` = 1 has `elems` of 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004. This works with `id` 2 too.

**Another example:**

[image]

This time the query should return `id` 1 and `elems` 1004 because `elems` 1004 doesn't exist in table 2 where `id` = 1.

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXCEPT DISTINCT` for this in BigQuery:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
EXCEPT DISTINCT 
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

It will return the rows from the first table which aren't present in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

you don't even need `DISTINCT`. Set operators like EXCEPT, UNION (without ALL), MINUS, INTERSECT, between SELECTs, imply  DISTINCT - or should.

First example:

```
WITH
tb1(id,elems) AS (
            SELECT 1,1001
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,1002
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,1004
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1001
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1003
)
,
tb2(id,elems) AS (
            SELECT 1,1001
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,1002
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,1003
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,1004
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1001
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1003
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1003
)
SELECT * FROM tb1
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM tb2;
 id | elems 
----+-------
(0 rows)
```

2nd example:

```
WITH
tb1(id,elems) AS (
            SELECT 1,1001
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,1002
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,1004
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1001
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1003
)
,
tb2(id,elems) AS (
            SELECT 1,1001
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,1002
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,1003
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1001
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1003
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1003
)
SELECT * FROM tb1
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM tb2;
 id | elems 
----+-------
  1 |  1004
(1 row)
```